# How to write Pivot

Tags: sql-server-2008, pivot-table

I have a table with date column like

```
DEPT_NAME   EMP_NAME    DESIGNATION DAY FIRST_SHIFT SECOND_SHIFT    THIRD_SHIFT GENERAL_SHIFT
C & I   DHAS YOGESH BABASAHEB   Diploma - Sr. Technician    01-3-13 0   0   0   0
C & I   DHAS YOGESH BABASAHEB   Diploma - Sr. Technician    02-3-13 0   0   0   0
C & I   DHAS YOGESH BABASAHEB   Diploma - Sr. Technician    03-3-13 0   0   0   0
```

i want to

```
DEPT_NAME      EMP_NAME DESIGNATION 01-03-13                02-03-13    03-03-13


C & I   DHAS YOGESH BABASAHEB   Diploma - Sr. Technician 0 0 0 0     0 0 0 0     0 0 0 0
```

Please help me...!!!

Comment: Which column do you want to pivot on? The DESIGNATION DAY is the one you want in the header right? But the value is it FIRST_SHIFT? What have you tried? There is a lot of examples both [msdn](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) and on SO

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. i have a day column, in a day i have 4 shifts. so i want to dislplay day column in header and 4 shifts have t o come in row with comma separator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

First some test data:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl
(
    DEPT_NAME VARCHAR(200),
    EMP_NAME VARCHAR(200),
    DESIGNATION VARCHAR(200),
    [DAY] DATE,
    FIRST_SHIFT INT,
    SECOND_SHIFT INT,
    THIRD_SHIFT INT,
    GENERAL_SHIFT INT
)
INSERT INTO tbl
VALUES
('C & I','DHAS YOGESH BABASAHEB','Diploma - Sr. Technician','01-3-13',0,0,0,0),
('C & I','DHAS YOGESH BABASAHEB','Diploma - Sr. Technician','02-3-13',0,0,0,0),
('C & I','DHAS YOGESH BABASAHEB','Diploma - Sr. Technician','03-3-13',0,0,0,0)
```

The concating the unique columns:

```
DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(MAX)
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tbl.[DAY] ORDER BY tbl.[DAY]) AS rowNbr,
        tbl.[DAY]
    FROM
        tbl
)
SELECT @cols=STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT
            ',' +QUOTENAME([DAY])
        FROM
            CTE
        WHERE
            CTE.rowNbr=1
        FOR XML PATH('')
    )
,1,1,'')
```

Then execute the dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000)=
N'SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        tbl.DEPT_NAME,
        tbl.EMP_NAME,
        tbl.DESIGNATION,
        tbl.[DAY],
        (
            CAST(tbl.FIRST_SHIFT AS VARCHAR(10))+'' ''+
            CAST(tbl.SECOND_SHIFT AS VARCHAR(10))+'' ''+
            CAST(tbl.THIRD_SHIFT AS VARCHAR(10))+'' ''+
            CAST(tbl.GENERAL_SHIFT AS VARCHAR(10))
        ) AS SHIFT
    FROM
        tbl
) AS p
PIVOT
(
    MAX(SHIFT) FOR [DAY] IN('+@cols+')
) AS pvt'

EXECUTE(@query)
```

And in my case dropping the created tables:

```
DROP TABLE tbl
```

Output will be:

```
DEPT_NAME    EMP_NAME                DESIGNATION               2013-01-03   2013-02-03    2013-03-03
C & I        DHAS YOGESH BABASAHEB   Diploma - Sr. Technician  0 0 0 0      0 0 0 0       0 0 0 0
```